# Scp locate's output by Xargs

Tags: scp, xargs, locate

I want to make a list of files of locate's output.
I want `scp` to take the list.

I am not sure about the syntax.
My attempt with pseudo-code

```
locate labra | xargs scp {} masi@11.11.11:~/Desktop/
```

How can you move the files to the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, {} is a **find**ism:

```
find ... -exec cmd {} \;
```

Where {} is the current file that find is working on.

You can get **xargs** to behave similar with:

```
locate labra | xargs -I{} echo {} more arguments
```

However, you'll quickly notice that it runs the commands multiple times instead of one call to **scp**.

So in the context of your example:

```
locate labra | xargs -I{} scp '{}' masi@11.11.11:~/Desktop/
```

Notice the single quotes around the {} as it'll be useful for paths with spaces in them.

Comment: downvote because you mention the problem that `xargs` will call `scp` one time for every input file but there's no solution. As the question is explicitly about using `scp` I'd expect that. Also you recommend using single quotes like `'{}'`--the quotes are eaten by your shell and make no difference at all.

Answer (score 3):

xargs normally takes as many arguments it can fit on the command line, but using -I it suddenly only takes one. GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ may be a better solution:

```
locate labra | parallel -m scp {} masi@11.11.11:~/Desktop/
```

Since you are looking at scp, may I suggest you also check out rsync?

```
locate labra | parallel -m rsync -az {} masi@11.11.11:~/Desktop/
```